# Using Powershell command to send output to text file outputs word wrapped text?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

In a Windows shell script, I'm running

`` for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (`powershell "get-physicaldisk | format-list"`) do echo %%a %%b ``

The very first line it encounters is:

```
ObjectId                     : {1}\\ERNIE-WIN10PRO\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Provi
                               ders_v2\SPACES_PhysicalDisk.ObjectId="{b8c6f511-2d7d-11
                               ec-971a-806e6f6e6963}:PD:{b02a7c27-2f8e-743f-233c-f60a0
                               a1ce840}"
```

It echoes %%a as "ObjectId" but it cuts off %%b exactly as shown above...

> {1}\ERNIE-WIN10PRO\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Provi

If I stretch the CMD window so that it cuts off (e.g.) after "SPACES", then that's where %%b gets cut off. Not only is this a problem as far as getting the full %%b value, but it causes the next line to fail with

> ders was not expected at this time.

This seems like such odd behavior. Why on earth is it happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not sure why you would go from powershell to cmd when powershell is far superior in any aspect I can imagine. In any case, `Format-List` is meant exclusively for displaying information to the PS Console. If you want to send results from PS to CMD you should feed CMD with something you can manipulate like CSV. See `ConvertTo-Csv`.

Comment: CMD is what I know. I've been doing batch files for 20+ years. Old dog... old tricks. Thanks for the CSV suggestion; I'll take a look.

Comment: `powershell "Get-PhysicalDisk | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation"` should be something you could manipulate on CMD.

Comment: Thank you, Santiago! I can work with that.